# Proving that a parametric equation define a specific surface

Tags: geometry, surfaces, parametric

Exercise 2b, §2, chapter 3 of "Using algebraic geometry" by D. Cox, J. Little and D. O' Shea asks the reader to show that the parametric equations $(x,y,z)=(st,s^2t,st^2)$ define the surface $x^3=yz$. Now, this is most probably a very easy question since the difficult part comes after, but I have some trouble. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

$$x=st,y=s^2t,z=st^2$$
$$yz=s^3t^3=(st)^3=x^3$$

Comment: Yes I checked that, but I thought that the word "define" on the problem meant something more. Actually I tried to show that the function $\phi(s,t)=(st,s^2t,st^2)$ can be used to define a chart and subsequently a differential atlas but it is not easy. I will leave it open for a while in case someone points something out and then close it.